# Is it right to remove salt & pepper effect from a product produced by clean images?

Tags: grass-gis, noise

I have two images from classification (different years) and I want to find the changes of land cover . I have cleaned the two images (salt and pepper). When I create  a cross product of the category values from these images I get an image with a lot of "noise". I want to know If it is right to clean that image or not(because it is a product of two clean images). I use grass and the final image created with "cross".

Comment: Could you tell us what you mean by "noise"? It is difficult to conceive of how a difference between two cleaned images could be construed as having *independent random* variations in the pixels, which is the common meaning of "noise", so some characterization of what you are seeing in the difference of the images might clarify the question.